# WCF service / Method not allowed

Tags: c#, wcf

I am trying to get a WCF service running. So I extended an example from MSDN but if I call the "EchoPerson()" or "EchoWithTest(s string)" I will get a fault "405 Method not allowed". If I call it from the code (channel.EchoPerson()) it will work, if I call it from Webbrowser with GET it does not work.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ServiceModel;
using System.ServiceModel.Description;
using System.ServiceModel.Web;
using System.Text;
using System.Web.Script.Serialization;

namespace ConsoleApplication2
{
    [ServiceContract]
    public interface IService
    {
        [OperationContract]
        [WebGet]
        string EchoWithGet(string s);

        [OperationContract]
        [WebInvoke]
        string EchoWithPost(string s);

        [OperationContract]
        [WebInvoke]
        string EchoWithTest(string s);

        [OperationContract]
        [WebInvoke]
        string EchoPerson();
    }

    public class Person
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int Age { get; set; }
        public double Shoesize { get; set; }

    }

    public class Service : IService
    {
        public string EchoWithGet(string s)
        {
            return "You said " + s;
        }

        public string EchoWithTest(string s)
        {
            return "You said " + s;
        }

        public string EchoWithPost(string s)
        {
            return "You said " + s;
        }

        //[WebInvoke(Method = "GET",
        //    ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
        //    UriTemplate = "data/{id}")]
        public string EchoPerson()
        {
            Person testPerson = new Person()
            {
                Name = "TestPerson",
                Age = 12,
                Shoesize = 9.5
            };

            string s1 = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(testPerson);

            return s1;
        }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            WebServiceHost host = new WebServiceHost(typeof(Service), new Uri("http://localhost:8000/"));
            try
            {
                ServiceEndpoint ep = host.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IService), new WebHttpBinding(), "");
                host.Open();
                using (ChannelFactory<IService> cf = new ChannelFactory<IService>(new WebHttpBinding(), "http://localhost:8000"))
                {
                    cf.Endpoint.Behaviors.Add(new WebHttpBehavior());

                    IService channel = cf.CreateChannel();

                    string s;

                    Console.WriteLine("Calling EchoWithGet via HTTP GET: ");
                    s = channel.EchoWithGet("Hello, world");
                    Console.WriteLine("   Output: {0}", s);

                    Console.WriteLine("");
                    Console.WriteLine("This can also be accomplished by navigating to");
                    Console.WriteLine("http://localhost:8000/EchoWithGet?s=Hello, world!");
                    Console.WriteLine("in a web browser while this sample is running.");

                    Console.WriteLine("");
                    s = channel.EchoPerson();
                    Console.WriteLine("   Output: {0}", s);

                    Console.WriteLine("Calling EchoWithPost via HTTP POST: ");
                    s = channel.EchoWithPost("Hello, world");
                    Console.WriteLine("   Output: {0}", s);
                    Console.WriteLine("");
                }

                Console.WriteLine("Press <ENTER> to terminate");
                Console.ReadLine();

                host.Close();
            }
            catch (CommunicationException cex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("An exception occurred: {0}", cex.Message);
                Console.ReadLine();
                host.Abort();
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: That sounds like the expected behavior.  `WebInvoke` == `POST`, `WebGet` == `GET`.  You can use something like Fiddler or CURL to build a `POST` request for testing.

Comment: The strange thing is http://localhost:8000/EchoWithGet?s=Hello will work with GET but http://localhost:8000/EchoWithTest?s=Hello answers with 405-Fault.
I cannot see the difference between both Methods.

Comment: The contract determines the accepted methods.  `[WebInvoke] string EchoWithTest(string s);` is mandating `POST`.  If you want it to be `GET`, change it to be `[WebGet] string EchoWithTest(string s);`

Comment: Thanks, that was the problem! Stupid that I did not see it by myself!!